# Word for "Doing what you think is right instead of what other people think is right"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Potentially a silly question: I was watching [this video](https://youtu.be/Z7iBD9l4FUU?t=7m38s) and heard this. It may be because I'm not a native speaker, but I believe I haven't heard it before? All my searches lead to the word 'inhibition' which is more or less the opposite of this definition. Any clarification of what Candice said/tried to say there, or any alternative words?

Comment: It's "following your heart" !!

Comment: Anti-Marxism? ("Those are my principles, and if you don't like them... well, I have others." – Groucho Marx)

Comment: Maybe *scruples*. This word is heavy on morality and ethics, though.

Comment: ...untrammeled.

Answer (score 4):

I would call it **integrity** - being true to yourself.

About integrity:

*"a moral compass that doesn't waver"* - [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/integrity)

*"a personal choice to hold oneself to consistent moral and ethical standards"* [- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrity)

Answer (score 0):

> **have the courage of one's convictions**, *to act in accordance with one's beliefs, especially in spite of criticism*.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/have-the-courage-of-one-s-convictions)

(I'll note that "have the *strength* of one's convictions" is more familiar to me, but some sites suggest that it's archaic.)